# Can you use regression to predict values if you imputed data using MICE?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, multiple-imputation

I used multiple imputation on a data set that had some missing values (I had to do this as the sample size was low so I couldn't just exclude the NAs). I know you can do

```
*read in dataset*
d <- mice(dat)
fit <- with(data = d, exp = glm(Condition ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4)) 
combine <- pool(fit)
summary(combine)
```

But are you able to extract predicted values from this model? For example I want the probabilities of individuals being in the control or treatment condition. Normally this would be done like

```
predict(fit, d, type = 'response')
```

However I can't seem to make this work. Could I do a prediction for each dataset and average the predicted values? For example:

```
d <- mice(dat)
a <- complete(d, 1)
fit <- glm(Condition ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4, family = 'binomial')
predict(fit, a, type = 'response)
```

And do this for all datasets then take an average of the predicted values.
Or would this logic be flawed and is there any other way to do it?

Comment: The idea is to pool the results, so you would pool the predictions from multiple models in some way, say average.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `pool` function in the `mice` package. The description of that function says:

The pool() function combines the estimates from m repeated complete data analyses. The typical
sequence of steps to perform a multiple imputation analysis is:

> 1. Impute the missing data by the mice() function, resulting in a multiple imputed data set (class mids);
> 2. Fit the model of interest (scientific model) on each imputed data set by the with() function, resulting an object of class mira;
> 3. Pool the estimates from each model into a single set of estimates and standard errors, resulting in an object of class mipo;
> 4. Optionally, compare pooled estimates from different scientific models by the
>    D1() or D3() functions. A common error is reverse steps 2 and 3, i.e.,
>    to pool the multiply-imputed data instead of the estimates. Doing so
>    may severely bias the estimates of scientific interest and yield
>    incorrect statistical intervals and p-values. The pool() function will
>    detect this case.